Will compressing a gas but keeping the temperature constant allow me to compress it further without significant resistance?
Let‘s say we compress a cylinder with gas. If I make sure to cool the cylinder to keep it at ambient temperature, will the force needed to compress the air also stay constant? If not, how much will it get harder to compress the air?
I‘ve read a bit about Faradays liquefication method and it seems that he used it for liquefying chlorine. Would his method be feasible with let‘s say nitrogen?

Consider that if you could do this, you could easily compress an arbitrary quantity of gas to effectively zero volume - place a weight on top of a piston, let it passively equilibrate temperature with its surroundings, and then keep compressing with exactly the same applied force.

Seems logical, haven‘t thought about that.

You have asked several questions.  For ideal gas involving no phase change, the equation of state is PV=nRT, so, at constant temperature, if the volume decreases, the pressure must be increased.
For a pure substance involving liquification at constant temperature, compressing in this way takes place at constant temperature and pressure.
So, there is a big difference compressing a gas at constant temperature from compressing to liquify a gas (phase change).

Sorry I‘m new to this topic. I understand the first part now. But i don‘t quite get the part with the liquefaction process. Could you elaborate on that?

When a pure gas condenses at constant temperature, its pressure is also constant.  What varies is the fraction of liquid and vapor.

The constant temperature compression of a gas cannot be accomplished by a constant force (constant pressure). It requires that the product of the pressure and volume be constant. For an ideal gas that means $PV=nRT$ where $T$, $n$ and $R$ are all constants. So as the volume decreases the pressure must increase.
Hope this helps.

The isothermal volumetric stiffness of a material—the isothermal bulk modulus—is
$$K\equiv -V\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_{T},$$
where the subscript indicates a variable held constant during the differentiation.
For an ideal gas ($PV=nRT$), one can verify that $K=\frac{nRT}{V}=P$. The compression resistance of a gas thus increases with compression, even if the volume is held constant.
